# MS SQL no warning when inserting DateTime to Date column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
create table t1 (d date not null)
insert into t2 (d) values ('1988-02-01 14:23:30'); // inserting whole dateTime, no warning or error
select * from [Test].[dbo].[t1] // 1988-02-01
```

Where can I set that ms sql server would throw error in case we are inserting whole datetime to date column. I noticed this because C# translates ms sql `date` or `datetime` to c# `datetime`.

Comment: SQL server silently truncates datetime values to date values.  I don't know of any way to cause an error in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`DATE` and `DATETIME` are related very closely. I did not check, wheter an `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` could help, but I doubt this.

I'd advise you to create the field as `DATETIME` and add a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

```
CREATE TABLE dummy(d DATETIME CONSTRAINT CK_dummy_d CHECK(d=CAST(d AS DATE)));
--This works
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES({d'2016-10-13'});
SELECT * FROM dummy;

--This runs against the check constraint
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES(GETDATE());
SELECT * FROM dummy;
GO

DROP TABLE dummy;
```

Answer (score 0):

change format date to datetime because your insert date with time

```
 create table t1 (d datetime not null)
 insert into t1 (d) values ('1988-02-01 14:23:30'); 
 select * from [Test].[dbo].[t1] // 1988-02-01
```

Comment: Yes, that would be solution, but currently I'm not in charge (entitled) to change database schema.